# Copying shared folder between two servers automatically

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, shared-folders, file-server

I have two Windows server (`server A` and `server B`) which I use for sharing folders (as file servers). I want one shared folder in `server A` to be copied with its data automatically & periodically to another shared folder in `server B` at a specific time, lets say 12:00 AM.

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle this is a scheduled task running daily at 12AM using `robocopy` on `ServerA`. The command line for the scheduled task would be `robocopy drive:\path\to\share \\ServerB\share /mir`. Robocopy has MANY more options that you may want to explore but this simple syntax will mirror a directory structure from the first path to the second.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with servers, but since they're Windows, I guess I can assume what works on Windows PCs should theoretically work there. These are the solutions I think would work on a PC.

- If it's not too large an amount of data, any cloud syncing service would do the job: Dropbox, Skydrive, etc. This would be by far your easiest option, though it does use bandwidth by transferring files to the cloud servers as well.
- Something like SVN can do just that, on top of keeping revisions/backups.
- I'm pretty sure some FTP software (there has to be some for servers as well, right?) have settings to do such automatic sends.
- You could also use the task scheduler to tell the machine to send the folder to the other machine daily. If you're more, let's say, advanced, you can probably get it to only send the files that have been updated since the last transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoFileMove](http://www.autofilemove.com/) to build transfer schedules which will automate files transfers and keep both servers sync.
You can do the same between ftp, dropbox or amazon s3.